# How to Update specific object in nested array?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, nested

Im having a problem with updating an object in nested array.

My current schema looks like this:

```
const nested = new Schema({
school: {
  type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
  required: true,
  ref: 'School',
},

lastActiveAt: {
  type: Date,
  },
},    
{ _id: false }
);

userSchema = new Schema({
...,
schools: [nested]
})
```

Each user has schools array, which has multiple schools he is connected with and a timestamp of last activity for that school. Now I need to update timestamp accordingly, and im having troubles to do so.

```
await userSchema.findOneAndUpdate(
{
_id: req.body.userId,
},
{
$set: { 'schools.$[element].lastActiveAt': new Date().toISOString() },
},
{
arrayFilters: [{ 'element.school': req.body.school }],
});
```

Ive tried doing it in shell with db.users.updateOne(...query) - it works.
Also Robo3t shell works as well
Not sure where to go since ive read more than 200 pages of docs and online articles

Comment: maybe add the error message ... , it looks you have some syntax error ...

Comment: possibly from manual typing this over here..but there are no errors, it jsut wont work through nodejs/mongoose